# Array Passed in Props Showing Up as Empty

Tags: reactjs

I can't get my head wrapped around this behavior. In the console log message of the App component, arr shows as an array with 2 element as expected. However, when it's passed down to the ChildComponent, it shows as an empty array. If instead of using splice on the pokemon array directly, I first spread it to a new array, and then use splice on that, it works fine.

Obviously it's because splice changes the array directly, which goes against React rule of immutability, but I cant figure out why that matters when the pokemon array isn't what being passed to the child component.

```
const pokemon = [
  {
    name: 'pikachu'
  },
  {
    name: 'raichu'
  }
]

export default function App() {
  const arr = pokemon.splice(0,2)
  console.log(arr)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChildComponent example={arr} />
    </div>
  );
}

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      hi
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actually reason you face this strange behavior is because your code `App` is wrapped with [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) that renders your component twice.

Splice at first returns the removed items, then pokemon has none left after first splice. `arr` prints these remove items. Because you app is wrapped with `StrictMode` (app gets executed again), pokemon (which now is an empty array) gets spliced again, and Child has an empty array printing an empty array.

If you remove `StrictMode` wrap, your code will behave as expected and both `console.log` will print correctly.

Comment: That was it. Just as you said, without StrictMode, it functions as expected. Is it expected that that the console.log on the App component only execute on the first render? Shouldn't it also execute on the 2nd render, following the splice of an empty array, and result in an additional log message of an empty 'arr' array?

Comment: Found this [post](https://dev.to/sebastianstamm/be-careful-with-console-log-when-using-react-strictmode-ah9) that explains it.  "It turns out that React is hijacking console.log and is replacing it with a function that does nothing on the second render pass"